# Centralised user ID tracking for multiple models in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using different models for different user types.

Suppose there are two models, `Student` and `Teacher`
Each model will have an ID field, `student_id` and `teacher_id` respectively.

Both of these ID fields start with `1` and are not dependent on each other.

So, the first teacher and the first student will have the same id, `student_id` would be `1` and `teacher_id` would be `1`

Now I want to modify devise such that, if a User has an ID of `1` then the teacher created after that should take it into account and have an ID of `2` (instead of 1).

This helps identify each user (of any type) separately, as no two IDs would be the same.

Or is there any other way to get the result instead of configuring devise?

Answer (score 0):

I would use only one model, e.g. User.

Additional to all your user-stuff (name, email etc.) I would add a enum type, e.g user_type:

```
enum user_type: [ :teacher, :student ]
```

Your migration shoul look likes this example:

```
def change
  create_table :users do |t|
    t.string  :email, null: false
    t.string  :first_name
    t.string  :last_name
    t.string  :password_digest, null: false
    t.integer :user_type, null: false

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

Using the enum type allows you to find teachers with `users.teacher.all` and students with `users.student.all`.

All users are stored in the same table, and you can add more user_types if needed.

In your database all teachers will have a 0 in the user_type column, the students will have a 1.

If you add more user_types, e.g guests, your model looks like

```
enum user_type: [ :teacher, :student, :guest ]
```

and all guests will have a 2 in the user_type column and so on.

More about enums in models is described in the [rails api](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

EDIT:

In case that you really want to use two different models you have to write your own method.

Very simplified:

```
def next_id
  Student.last.id > Teacher.last.id ? Student.last.id + 1 : Teacher.last.id +1
end
```

Include this method in both models (maybe you want to use a concern) and use the next_id when creating a record:

```
Student.create(id: Student.next_id, name: 'John'....)
```

In my opinion the second way seems to be awkward. I would always prefer the enum example.

Comment: Thanks :) I came across that, but my app is using two separate models. For my application breaking down seemed to be a better option (for scaling issues). So, I'm looking for something specifically on two separate models.

Comment: I've edited my answer. As far as I can see devise offers no built-in way to solve your problem, so you have to do it with by your own.